# Could I replace or slice dash in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops, replace

Can I replace the dash in array until end of the string in array?
If I have

```
["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ]
```

And I wantr the output to be array

```
["Doni", "Mike"]
```

Or we should use loop to slice them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var arr = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ];
arr = arr.map(n => n.split('-')[0]);
console.log(arr);
```

Using *for* loop:

```js
var arr = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].split('-')[0];
}
console.log(arr);
```

Using `forEach()`:

```js
var arr = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ];
arr.forEach((n,i) => {
  arr[i] = arr[i].split('-')[0];
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is the most efficient answer of all.

Comment: how about if we dont use `map` ??

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()` in `.map()` to remove additional part of string from all items.

```js
var arr = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ];
var newArr = arr.map(function(val){
  return val.replace(/-.*/, '');
});
console.log(newArr);
```

The code in ES6

```js
var arr = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ];
console.log(arr.map(val => val.replace(/-.*/, '')));
```

Also you can use `for` loop instead of `.map()` if you want.

```js
var arr = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night" ];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/-.*/, '');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: how about if we dont use `map` ??

Comment: @iLnx You can use `for` loop that added in answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression which replace the dash an all following characters until the end of the string.

```js
var array = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night"];

array = array.map(s => s.replace(/-.*$/, ''));

console.log(array);
```

With a `for` loop and an index.

```js
var array = ["Doni-night", "Mike-night"],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].replace(/-.*$/, '');
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: how about if we dont use `map` ??